# Remove escape sequence in c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I would like to replace the escape sequence from string `test= "\"hi hello\" "` to string `test=" "hi hello" "`. Basically I want to replace `\"` to `"`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a string you are typing directly into the code or is it from an external source, e.g. a file?

Comment: @james- it is the string which comes from the programming context. follow this link to know the core problem I have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558130/convert-html-to-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as if you remove the escape sequences, you will have an invalid string.

You can use verbatim string literals, but these also require escaping of double quotes.

Can you please explain why you want to remove the escape sequences? They will not be visible when you output a string.

The debugger will display the escape sequences as an aid, but if you output the string, you will not see them.

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("\"hi there \"");
// outputs "hi there "
```

Comment: By "escape sequence" I think he just meant the quoted double quote character.

Comment: @Larry Watanabe - the question has the specific example that `\"` should be changed to `"`.

Comment: Here is the link that explains why I need to remove escape sequence http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558130/convert-html-to-a-string .I need to give a shot by removing the escape sequences

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "\"hi hello\" ";
test.Replace("\"", "");
Console.Out.WriteLine(test);
```

This produces

hi hello

on the Console.

Comment: I need output like "hi hello" I just need to remove the \ not \"

Comment: @Maddy - If you leave the string as it is in the first line without any replaces, it will produce `"hi hello"`. You don't need to remove the escape sequence, in fact, you need it.

Comment: I agree with your comment but the core aim is to replace \" with ". follow this post to know why need to eliminate escape sequence.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558130/convert-html-to-a-string

Comment: @Maddy, Oded s correct. You can't make arbitary changes to the string and get the same output - that's like asking how can you remove all the vowels from the string and still get "hi hello"

Answer (score -1):

```
test = test.Replace("\\", "");
```

If you're not looking for replacing `\` in a string, your options are limited to a verbatim string:

```
string test = @" ""hi hello"" ";
```

Note the `\"` was replaced with `""`