# Error when exporting data to PDF from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a PDF file from C# like this:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
Response.Write("<table border='1px'>");

/* Print Headers */
Response.Write("<tr>");
Response.Write("<th colspan='" + colspan + "'style='background-color:SlateGray;font-size:16;height:25;color:white;'><b>List of Candidates  "</b></th>");
Response.Write("</tr>");
Response.Write("<tr>");
```

When I save the file and open it, it throws an exception that file is not supported file type .. or file has been damaged.

Comment: you are writing tr,td and wants to export it in pdf? its not possible.. you should try have a look at iTextSharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create pdf form html you should have a look at it.

[Render PDF in iTextSharp from HTML with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430280/render-pdf-in-itextsharp-from-html-with-css)

to create tables using itextsharp have a look at it

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables