# Set width of table cell in PDF ITextSharp

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp to convert html table to pdf.

It working fine but the width property is not working in PDF. Means when you change fix the width of column of a table to 20% or 20px its not reflecting on PDF .

How to set the width of column in PDF?

My Code :

```
"<table border='1'>"
    + "<thead><tr>" 
        + "<th style='width:10%;'>ID</th>"
        + "<th style='width:70%;'>Testing Point</th>"
        + "<th style='width:20%;'>Notes</th>"
    + "</tr></thead></table>"
```

Above code is showing table with border but total width of PDF is divided into 3 part. Each cell taking same width.

How can i fix the width of a table so that it will take user defined column width.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [itextsharp does not care my html styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918642/itextsharp-does-not-care-my-html-styles)

Answer (score 2):

you must set td width in percentage for  td in each row, not just in header row.

```
<table width="75%">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col" width="10%">&nbsp;</th>    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does not work on older versions of ITextSharp. So be sure that you are using the latest version!